# Changing mutiple integers into one character

Tags: r, vector, integer, character

How would go about changing the list

```
> test
[1]  61  84  85  94  99 101 131 132
```

To a singular character

```
> char
[1] "61,  84,  85,  94,  99, 101, 131, 132"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
toString(test)
```

giving:

```
[1] "61, 84, 85, 94, 99, 101, 131, 132"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paste`

```
paste(test, collapse=", ")
#[1] "61, 84, 85, 94, 99, 101, 131, 132"
```

EDIT:

```
toString.default
function (x, width = NULL, ...) 
{
   string <- paste(x, collapse = ", ") ####
------------------------
```